# Error while using XPath to parse text from HTML

Tags: c#, html, xpath

The HTML content I need to parse is the text in the marquee element as given below. I'm using C# with HTML Agility Pack to parse it, but a nullrefrence exception is thrown.

C# code is

```
var ht1 = ht.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/marquee/text()").InnerText;
```

Part of HTML:

```
<html>
   -<body ...
      -<table id=..
         -<tbody>
           -<tr>
             +<td.........
             -<td
               +<div ......
               -<div style="width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;border
                -style:solid;border-width:0;border-color:darkred;">
                  <marquee width="100%" height="20" bgcolor="" style="color:
                  darkorchid; font-size: 14" loop="3" behavior="scroll" 
                  scrolldelay="90 scrollamount="5" align="middle" border="0">
                   your scrolling text - these are some samples - think  of
                   possibilities</marquee>
                  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you look in the direct source of the html file? If you only look in the html shown in a browser like Firebug/fox, it shows additional tbody tags, that are not actually in the file.
   Therefore use:

   ```
   var ht1 = ht.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/body/table/tr/td[2]/div[2]/marquee/text()").InnerText;
   ```
2. You usually do not want to use text() because, the text content of a node is already its text. And text() returns a set of text-nodes, not the concatenated text.
   Therefore use:

   ```
   var ht1 = ht.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/body/table/tr/td[2]/div[2]/marquee").InnerText
   ```

Comment: var ht1 = ht.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/body/table/tr/td[2]/div[2]/marquee").InnerText never worked so i added text(),that didn't helped too.

Comment: http://www.ezcybersites.com/html-goodies/marque-html-code-creator.html     is the link for website.

Comment: Ok that page source is completely broken. The best is to just use `(//marquee)[1]` to get the first marquee

Answer (score 0):

That page does not seem to be well formed HTML.
This worked for me though:

```
ht.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"html/head/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/td/div[2]/marquee").InnerText;
```